# Package for SMOTEBoost in R

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, sampling

I am solving a rare event cum classification problem. I have come across  a package called **SMOTEBoost** which oversamples the rare event and boost the results. But I'm not sure is that supported in R.

Could you please help me how can I use SMOTEBoost in R? Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

There are two packages in `R` that should be able to use `SMOTE` to up sample the minority class:

1. `unbalanced` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/unbalanced/unbalanced.pdf), and
2. `DMwR` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DMwR/DMwR.pdf)

It doesn't seem like they provide the boosting that is described in the [paper](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~aleks/papers/pkdd03.pdf) that you might be referring to. But it should be straightforward to sew in `SMOTE` with the idea of boosting using some base tree packages in R like `rpart` (for example).